# Unexpected perl regex substitution output in makefile using fgrep

Tags: regex, perl, makefile, grep, piping

Inspired by this rule by *prwhite* on GitHub

```
help:
    @fgrep -h "##" $(MAKEFILE_LIST) | fgrep -v fgrep | sed -e 's/\\$$//' | sed -e 's/##//'`
```

I'm trying to make a version that replaces target files with spaces. I want to replace a part of a string with all spaces.
With the file `input.txt`:

```
spec: $(ALL_FILES)      ## Runs all specs
myst-spec: $(ALL_FILES) ## Runs just the in-language specs
build: $(SOURCE_FILES)   ## Builds myst into an executable
check: $(ALL_FILES)     ## Runs all crystal specs
clean:                  ## Cleans (deletes) docs and executables
help:                   ## Show this help.
```

This is the expected output:

```
spec:                   ## Runs all specs
myst-spec:              ## Runs just the in-language specs
build:                  ## Builds myst into an executable
check:                  ## Runs all crystal specs
clean:                  ## Cleans (deletes) docs and executables
help:                   ## Show this help.
```

This is the rule i currently have:

```
help:
    @fgrep -h "##" input.txt | fgrep -v fgrep | \
      perl -pe 's/(.*):(.*)##(.*)/("$1:" . (" " x length($2)) . " $3")/e'
```

Note that `fgrep` is used here, because actually this is supposed to be run on the makefile itself, but i use `input.txt` here so you don't have to deal with the whole makefile.

Unexpectedly, i get this output:

```
:
:
:
:
:
:
```

What confuses me the most is that if i run the perl script directly on `input.txt` (like this: `cat input.txt | perl -pe 's/(.*):(.*)##(.*)/("$1:" . (" " x length($2)) . " $3")/e'`) – i get the expected output. What is the reason it gives different output? I realize it (probably) has something to do with fgrep, but I don't see how it would make a difference, so here I am.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about removing the `@`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use `$` in a recipe you have to escape it from make by doubling it to `$$`.

```
help:
    @fgrep -h "##" input.txt | fgrep -v fgrep | \
      perl -pe 's/(.*):(.*)##(.*)/("$$1:" . (" " x length($$2)) . " $$3")/e'
```

The above can be simplified:

```
help:
    @perl -ne'next if !/##/; s/(.*):(.*)##(.*)/ "$$1:".( " " x length($$2) )." $$3" /e; print'
```

Or (5.10+):

```
help:
    @perl -ne'next if !/##/; s/:\K(.*)(?=##)/ " " x length($$1) /e; print'
```

Comment: It's interspersed with tab/space problems :).